# Forbid mouse to go up to menu bar area?

Tags: macos, mouse, blocking, lock

As it doesn't seem possible to disable the menu bar or at least increase the delay to make it reappear if hidden.

I am wondering if there is a way to forbid the mouse cursor to go over that area at the top of the screen unless holding a specific key for example ?
I just want to be abble to navigate through my different chrome tabs at the top of the screen without accidently toggling the menu bar.

Does anybody know of a way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Ctrl/Tab, Ctrl/Shift/Tab, or the Apple standard Cmd/Shift/ [ or ]